# ElectronでMenuが正しく表示されない

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

ElectronでMenuが正しく表示されません。
練習のためにmain processからMenuを表示させてみようとしています。

Menu.buildFromTemplateとMenu.setApplicationMenuで表示されるはずですが、うまくいきません。

applicationを起動すると、main.htmlはきちんと表示されます。
しかし、Menuが表示されません。
なぜなのでしょうか?

main.js (main process)

```
var v8 = require("v8");
v8.setFlagsFromString("--harmony_arrow_functions"); //ES2015のarrow functionを使えるようにするため

require("./process.js");
```

process.js

```
var Menu = require("menu");
var app = require("app");
var BrowserWindow = require("browser-window");
require("crash-reporter").start();

var template = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
{
    label: "ElectronPhoto",
    submemu: [
        {label: "About ElectronPhoto", click: () => {aboutWindow.show();}}
    ]
}
]);
app.on("ready", () => {
    var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({height: 660, width: 990});
    var aboutWindow = new BrowserWindow({height: 650, width: 300, show: false});
    mainWindow.loadUrl("file://" + __dirname + "/main.html");
    aboutWindow.loadUrl("file://" + __dirname + "/about.html");


    mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });

    app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
        if (process.platform != "darwin") {
            app.quit();
        }
    });


    Menu.setApplicationMenu(template);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`submenu`のタイプミスです。

```
        {
            label: "ElectronPhoto",
HERE------> submemu: [
                {label: "About ElectronPhoto", click: () => {aboutWindow.show();}}
            ]
        }
```